# Qt Type error between QML/real and C++/float

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have written my user interface with QML and need to pass some values from an Slider to a C++ class. The C++ class is exposed to QML via qmlRegisterType(). My slider is very simple and looks like this:

```
Slider {
    id: sliderCurForceR
    stepSize: 0.1
    value: 0.0
    onValueChanged: {
        con.CurForceR = value
    }
```

Where "con" is the ID of my C++ type I exposed to QML. onValueChanged I like to set the property CurForceR in "con" to the slider value. The property is defined as follow:

```
Q_PROPERTY(float CurForceR READ getCurForceR WRITE setCurForceR NOTIFY CurForceRChanged)

void setCurForceR(const float &force);
float getCurForceR();
```

Now when I run my program, I got an "TypeError: Type error" message which points to the assignment "con.CurForceR = value". However, it works as intended, I got the current value from my slider to my C++ property, but I like to get rid of this nasty error message/warning. I also tried to use the qreal type for the property, but same result. I also use an int property and get a value from a slider the same way, no errors there. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you sure you tried qreal with a clean build, double, too? Also, where is the Slider defined? There are so many component sets out there, are you using QtQuickControls? Which version of Qt? Also, how exactly is "con" exposed?

Comment: Hi, tanks for your fast answer :-) I am using Qt5.2, and QtQuick.Controls 1.1. I expose this class in the main function via qmlRegisterType<Myclass>("com.fhk", 1, 0, "Myclass");  I just changed the minimum value of the slider to 0 (before it was -10.0) and the message is gone. But I don't know why the warning pops up when the minimum value is below zero.

Comment: Out of the curiosity, are you using QGuiApplication or QApplication? Please provide an sscce.org compliant test case to reproduce the issue. It would be nice to investigate whether it is a Qt bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it. Simple failure... I forgot that the onValueChanged signal is emitted the first time when this slider is being initialized. Problem in my qml file was, I created the slider before the myclass type. So the property could not be accessed the first time, because the item which holds it is created shortly after the slider. But I still don't understand why the failure did not appear when the minimum Value is zero. Anyway, thanks a lot Laszlo, made me think more about this :-)